# SELECT data and COUNT comments in other mySql table

Tags: mysql

Hi there and thanks for looking into this.

I have the following query at this moment:

```
SELECT videos.video_genre_id, videos.username, videos.title, videos.slugTitle, videos.link, videos.tags, videos.date_added, video_genre.video_genre_id, video_genre.video_genre

FROM videos, video_genre
WHERE videos.accepted = 'y'
AND videos.video_genre_id = video_genre.video_genre_id
ORDER BY  videos.date_added DESC
```

Working fine. But I want to count the total comments for each video. I have another table named "video_comments" with the following fields:

```
video_comments_id 
videos_id 
comment
```

What is the best solution to use one query and get the total comments for each video? I never user COUNT before, so I don't know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The table "videos" has the field "videos_id" as the primary field.

Edit 2:

I think I got the answer:

```
    SELECT (select count(*) from video_comments AS total), videos.video_genre_id, videos.username, videos.title, videos.slugTitle, videos.link, videos.tags, videos.date_added, video_genre.video_genre_id, video_genre.video_genre
FROM videos, video_genre
WHERE videos.accepted = 'y'
AND videos.video_genre_id = video_genre.video_genre_id
ORDER BY  videos.date_added DESC
```

Only problem is that I can't seem to get "total" as a row to show the total comments.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM videos GROUP BY videos_id

Comment: Thanks everyone, but like you see in my second Edit, I'm trying to get the total number of comments for each video! It works fine in mysql this way, but I can't echo the row to show the total of comments.

Comment: A suggestion irrelevant to your question: Try to use singular in your tables and field names. You now have plural in some places (`videos`, `videos_id`), singular in others (`video_genre`) and mixed in some others (`video_comments`, `videos.title`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

`SELECT videos.video_genre_id, videos.username, videos.title, videos.slugTitle, videos.link, videos.tags, videos.date_added, video_genre.video_genre_id, video_genre.video_genre, COUNT(video_comments.videos_id)
FROM videos INNER JOIN video_genre ON videos.video_genre_id = video_genre.video_genre_id
LEFT JOIN video_comments ON video.id = video_comments.videos_id 
WHERE videos.accepted = 'y'
GROUP BY videos.video_genre_id, videos.username, videos.title, videos.slugTitle, videos.link, videos.tags, videos.date_added, video_genre.video_genre_id, video_genre.video_genre
ORDER BY  videos.date_added DESC`

I haven't tested it but that's the idea!

Comment: Thanks Johann. This did the trick when trying in the mysql database. Still need to figure out how to echo the total comments in PHP.

Comment: Just change `COUNT(video_comments.videos_id)` with `COUNT(video_comments.videos_id) AS commentCount`.
All being well you should be able use `commentCount` in PHP

Comment: It's really weird. I tried the same solution before you posted yours and it didn't work. Now it's working fine however. Guess I forgot something. Thanks for your help Johann! :)

Comment: This will work but it's not necessary to `GROUP BY` on all those columns. Only those that uniquely identify groups (the primary keys of the `videos` and `video_genre` tables) are enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT videos.video_genre_id
     , videos.username
     , videos.title
     , videos.slugTitle
     , videos.link
     , videos.tags
     , videos.date_added
     , video_genre.video_genre_id
     , video_genre.video_genre
     , COUNT(video_comments.video_comments_id) AS totalcomments
    FROM videos
        JOIN video_genre
            ON videos.video_genre_id = video_genre.video_genre_id
        JOIN video_comments
            ON video_comments.videos_id = videos.videos_id
    WHERE videos.accepted = 'y'
    GROUP BY videos.videos_id
           , video_genre.video_genre_id
    ORDER BY videos.date_added DESC
;
```

If you want videos without comments to appear as well (with totalcomments 0), change `JOIN video_comments` to `LEFT JOIN video_comments`.

Comment: This will probably fail because the SQL syntax checker doesn't see that the other fields in the results have unique values per group.  See Johann's answer for an amendment.

Comment: @reinierpost: I hit submit before finishing. It should work now.